# Register multiple completion routines

Tags: scala, rx-java

I have an `Observable` which is constructed from `Stream[Item]`(`Item` here is just for example)
This observable passes through a set of transformations:

```
val observable: Observable[Item] = ... //construct observable from stream
val observable1: Observable[AnotherItem1] = observable.map(...) //transform to AnotherItem1
val observable2: Observable[AnotherItem2] = observable1.map(...) //transform to AnotherItem2
```

I want to perform some actions on completion of each transformations (first and second).
If I call `doOncompleted` method on `observable1` and `observable2` I do not get the desired effect (actually I do not observe any side effects).

How can I accomplish this? Is this possible?

Comment: Do you expect your "actions" to execute after each `Item` is converted to a `AnotherItem1`, or after all the `observable` stream is converted to `observable1`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging some information with `.doOnNext()`? It could be that neither observables are being completed, explaining why `.doOnCompleted()` wasn't called. Make sure the observables are completed if you want to have a side effect on complete.

Comment: Will I get desired behaviour with such approach? I'm constructing observable as `val observable: Observable[Int] = Observable.from(Stream(1,2,3,4))`

Comment: It depends what behavior you want. You want to do side effects on completion, that is in `doOnCompleted`. It would help a lot if you would show what transformations are you doing (i.e., replace the `...` in the code).

Comment: Suppose I'm doing only `map` and `groupBy`

Comment: How is `observable1` dependent on observable? And `observable2`?

Comment: `observable1 = observable.map`, `observable2 = observable1.map`

Comment: also I've tried to call doOnNext and no side effects were observed